# UISearchBar set UITextField focus

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, focus, searchbar

I have an app (iOS7) like Facebook with menu sliding and search on the right slide.
What I want is to when `viewDidLoad` is called, to set focus on the `UITextField` of the search bar and shows the keyboard.

I’ve already tried the following:

```
for (id object in [[self.searchDisplayController searchBar] subviews])
{
    for (id subObject in [object subviews])
    {
        if ([subObject isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *textfield=(UITextField*)subObject;
            [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

But no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You need not to do this much UISearchdisplaycontroller has its own property.

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

One more thing I think your problem is you have not checked the tint color if it is white then your cursor is hidden, try setting some other tint color and you will find the focus by default.

Comment: Tks! I'll try it and post the results here!

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work.
I;ve set the bar tint and tint but still the same, and added the "[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];" in the "viewdidload" but didn't worked out.

Comment: Swift way: self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder();